# How to create internal dialog inside of an accordion in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, dialog, accordion

I need to make an internal dialog inside of an accordion in jQuery Mobile. The dialog code needs to be in the same file. I am having an easy time making an external dialog, though a very tough time creating one in the same file. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
    <h3> Internal Dialog Windows </h3>
    <p> 
        An internal dialog window in jQuery Mobile is similar to a popup window, though the internal dialog window requires some form of user interaction.
    </p>

    <div data-role="page" id="multipage-dialog">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>External Dialog Window</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <p>This is my external dialog window.</p>
            <p>     
                <a data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="plus" data-rel="back">GoBack</a> 
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is an internal dialog? Do you want something to popup above the collapsible like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/z7cuxufL/